# php,js creating json data

Tags: php, javascript, json

In php I have something like this:

```
$i=1; 
foreach ($result as $row){
    $outp['fields'][$i]['id']=$row['id'];
    $outp['fields'][$i]['x']=$row['x'];
    $outp['fields'][$i]['y']=$row['y'];
    $outp['fields'][$i]['type']=$row['type'];
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($outp)
```

And in the JS:

```
success: function(data) {
  var map = eval('(data)');
}
```

And here is the JSON output:

```
{"fields":
     {"1":{"id":9521,"x":21,"y":96,"type":2},
      "2":{"id":9522,"x":22,"y":96,"type":3},
      "3":{"id":9523,"x":23,"y":96,"type":1},
      "4":{"id":9930,"x":30,"y":100,"type":3}
     } 
}
```

I want to write html code for every field (4 fields in that case).
How can I do it? is this possible to convert var map into array?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(var i=1;i<=Object.keys(map["fields"]).length;i++){
    console.log(map["fields"][i]["id"]); //id
    console.log(map["fields"][i]["x"]);  //x
    console.log(map["fields"][i]["y"]);  //y
}
```

Comment: excellent! but if I want to write field inside loop like this
    $("#map").append("<div class='mapField'></div>"); it append just 3 fields(loop goes 50x), where can be problem?

Comment: Do you mean there are 50 elements in map["fields"]? Also, I forgot to write <= in for loop and updated my solution.

Comment: Could you post your problem in jsFiddle? I tried to do what you want in jsFiddle, and it worked. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/TQuLj/

Comment: hm, it really works on fiddle, but I have same code..my code goes through ajax but it can't be problem..thanks for help, I will must resolve it on my own